# AutoMapper how to map source object with child list to a dest list where each dest element has a property from the source object

Tags: automapper

How do a set up the mapping to map from the `Source` object and end up with just a list of `DestinationSetting`?  I've set up a map to go from `SourceSetting` to `DestinationSetting`, and that works fine, but obviously does not populate the `PersonID` property on `DestinationSetting`. I can't figure out how to get the `PersonID` from `Source` onto each of the destination objects.

```
public class Source
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public List<SourceSetting> Settings { get; set; }
}

public class SourceSetting
{
    public int SettingID  { get; set; }
    public string SettingValue { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationSetting
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int SettingID  { get; set; }
    public string SettingValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this is not clicking for me - I'm having trouble connecting that documentation to my specific case. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: A little research would help. There are _many_ similar questions.